# Quick questions about the new Mac Mini Server (2011)

Tags: hardware-recommendation, mac-mini

I'm planning to buy the new Mac Mini Server (2011), but I couldn't find the answer to a few questions:

1. I've read that it had an issue with its video card, but never found any site that details the so-called issue. Any idea what it is?
2. Can I just ignore the server stuff and user it as a normal OSX Lion and get the updates and all?
3. if I get the one with SSD, can I (easily) setup the system so that it runs off the SSD, and stores all the files in the HDD?
4. Do you think it will handle video editing in Final Cut Pro X well?

Appreciate your help! :)

Comment: I'm going to hope you to ask these as multiple questions  - but 1. the confusion is mostly people wanting another card - not that it is bad or doesn't work. 2. Yes - you can not install the server package even though you bought it. 3. yes - there are many ways to split the files - you can make it easy or complicated 4. The app will run like a champ for consumer video. If you feed it huge HD footage, you might need thunderbolt raid external and it won't chew through effects like a mac pro will.

Comment: (and you really don't want "all the files" on the HDD - you just want the large media ones there - run the SSD pretty close to capacity and only move things when it makes sense - the apps are happy moving them like iTunes media, video footage imports, etc....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On question #1, your best bet is the Apple Support forums. If there an issue, it should have been reported there by now.

On question number #2, you can ignore the server stuff and use the Mini as any other Mac with OS X Lion on it. You may need to tweak the default firewall settings but that is all I can think of.

On question number #3,  I have heard on different podcasts that people include both SSD's and HDD's in their Macs exactly like you want--system files on SSD, user files on HDD. [Other World Computing](http://www.macsales.com) is a good place to find SSD+HDD kits for the different Macs. I do not know if they offer one for the latest Mini, though.

On question #4, I cannot talk from experience with the current Mini. However, looking at its place within the Mac lineup alone, you can argue that eventually the Mini becomes their least capable Mac. While today's Mini has a recent Intel core architecture, and while you can in theory use a Thunderbolt drive as scratch disk when working on FCP X; just from my experience with the original Mini, I'd say that it will eventually fall short for your video editing needs.

Hope this helps.